# Simple 3D cube roll animations not working with threejs

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am new to THREEJS and at the moment I am trying to move a cube using arrow keys. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/y6cw7foj/26/

All works, I can move the cube using the arrow keys and I even managed to rotate the cube around the correct axis when moving it around. The problem is with the animations. I can’t seem to get them to work. At the moment when you press the left arrow key, the cube moves to the left and also rolls around the axis. Well…at the moment it snaps into position, instead of smoothly transitioning.

What I want is that it smoothly moves to the left while it rotates, but how to do that? At the end of the code I do call for the

```
requestAnimationFrame
```

but that doesn’t do much. I have a fiddle here of my attempt doing this with CSS. Here the animations work (but never got the rotating direction correct): https://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/5ozqg9uL/3/ This does show what animations I want to have.

So what am I missing in the THREEjs? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is something called "tweening," where you draw intermediary steps, rather than jumping immediately to the end result. There are several JavaScript libraries that will do this for you, but I'll cover some of the basics of implementing it yourself.

Take your example. When you tap the left arrow, you move the mesh `1` unit along the `-x` axis, and rotate `-PI/2` about the `+y` axis. Rather than snapping to these positions/rotations, consider how long you want the animation to take, and start dividing out steps.

Let's say you want to to take `500ms` (half a second). Your browser tries to run at about `60fps`, so you have `30` frames (about `500ms`) to work with at that rate. So for every frame, you can move the box `1/30` units, and rotate it by `-PI/60`. After `30` frames, the box should be in about the right place, give or take some rounding.

I use "about" when talking about the framerate of the browser because you aren't always guaranteed to get `60FPS`. If your framerates dip, and you're locked to the framerate to draw your animation, then it too will slow down and take longer than you wanted. So what can be done about that?

Rather than relying on `requestAnimationFrame` as your timer, you can set a *real* timer to step through your animation. Toss calculating the frames you need to complete the animation, and instead calculate the steps needed.

We already know that `60fps` is roughly `1` frame every `16.6ms`, so that's the absolute maximum target that can expect the browser to draw. But when we do our updates by steps, nothing stops us from going faster. To make things easier to calculate, let's say we want to do `50` update steps rather than the `30` from before. This means that for the `500ms` play time, we will need to perform an update every `10ms` (slightly faster than the framerate). Also, because we are performing 50 steps, we will be updating the position by `1/50` units, and rotating by `-PI/100`.

```js
let animationId = setInterval( ()=>{
  // update position by 1/50 units
  // update rotation by -PI/100
}, 10 ); // every 10 ms
```

As the interval runs, it will update the object. Meanwhile, the animation loop churns out new frames whenever it can.

Here's a full, running example, with only left-arrow support:

```js
let W = window.innerWidth;
let H = window.innerHeight;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
});
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 0, -1);
camera.add(light);

const cube = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: "red"
  })
);
cube.position.set(10, 0, 0);
scene.add(cube);

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resize() {
  W = window.innerWidth;
  H = window.innerHeight;
  renderer.setSize(W, H);
  camera.aspect = W / H;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  render();
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

resize();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

const yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

function updateCube() {
  //cube.position.x -= 1;
  //cube.rotateOnWorldAxis(yAxis, THREE.Math.degToRad(-90));
  cube.position.x -= 1 / 50;
  cube.rotateOnWorldAxis(yAxis, -(Math.PI / 100));
}

let step = 0;
let animationId = null;

function startStepping() {
  animationId = setInterval(() => {
    updateCube();
    if (++step === 50) {
      clearInterval(animationId);
      animationId = null;
    }
  }, 10)
}

function handleKeyboard(e) {
  //if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 37) {
  //  updateCube();
  //}
  if (animationId === null && (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 37)) {
    step = 0;
    startStepping();
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyboard, false);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Now there is a downside to this method. Sometimes you may see updates skipped (if the browser's framerate drops), or the same position drawn twice (if your update rate is significantly lower than the browser's framerate). You could try to get the best of both worlds but computing the framerate live from your render loop, and adjusting your frame steps accordingly, but at that point you must ask whether the extra time spent computing those statistics are actually hurting trying to achieve a rock-steady framerate-locked draw rate.

#### Switching based on key input

Because your key input is now disjointed from drawing, you now need some kind of flag to determine the action being taken. Your key press handler will set that flag, and then `updateCube` will act based on that flag. Something like:

```js
let action = null

function startStepping(){
  // set up the interval...
  // but then also ensure the action stops after the animation plays:
  setTimeout( () => action = null, 500 );
}

function handleKeyboard(e){
  if (animationId === null) {
    step = 0;

    switch(e.keyCode){
      case 37:
      case 65:
        action = "left";
        break;
      // other keys...
    }

    startStepping();
  }
}

function updateCube(){
  switch(action){
    case "left":
      // move as if it's rolling left
      break;
    case "right":
      // move as if it's rolling right
      break;
    // etc. for the other directions
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation. This helps a lot!!!

Comment: @Maurice If this answered your question, please remember to mark it as accepted, so others can see that your question has been answered.

Comment: I have one more question. Your example works great with only left-arrow support. How would I implement right arrow support too? I am trying to implement right arrow support but I am failing. I have tried adding  another IF in the handleKeyboard, but that doesn't update the updateCube() function cause it is in the startStepping() function. It must be something very simple I am missing here, but I am quite new to this. So how can I also add the right-arrow support? (I can figure out up and down myself when it's clear to me how to ad the right-arrow support). Thanks a lot

Comment: Think of it in stages. 1. Determine your direction and set some flags that indicate the chosen direction. 2. Start the timer. 3. When the timer fires, `updateCube` should use the directional flags to update in the correct direction. As long as you have `startStepping` blocked by the `animationId` check, it will block other inputs from interrupting the animation until it's done. Does that help?

Comment: Yes I understand that, but updateCube() has fixed values now. What do I need to put into: else if( event.keyCode == 68 || event.keyCode == 39) { } //right keypress. So updateCube() uses the values for moving to the right when pressed? Bit stuck with that part...

Comment: `updateCube` will contain your logic to decide what to do. Except rather than deciding based on key values, it must decide based on what the action flag is set to. See the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: This makes sense, I understand what you are saying. Thanks for taking the time to explain it further!